# Accessing attributes of object found with ActiveRecord.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm struggling with what would seem to be a simple concept. After using ActiveRecord query to get a single item, I want to access an attribute of that item but am getting **undefined method `msg' for nil:NilClass**

The models I'm using are as follows:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alias, :name
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  has_many :histories

  def lastActive
   return History.where(:provider_id => self.id).last
  end
end
```

and

```
class History < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  attr_accessible :available, :msg

  scope :active, where(:available => true)
  scope :recent, :limit => 1, :order => 'created_at DESC'

end
```

So, I have 2 different ways to get at the the most recent History item for a given Provider: Provider.lastActive and  provider.histories.active.recent.first. Both elude being able to get at any of the attributes of the History object that is being returned.

Using the Provider.lastActive in an erb method as in:

```
<%= provider.lastActive.msg  %>
```

yields **undefined method `msg' for nil:NilClass**

But,

```
<%= provider.lastActive.inspect  %>
```

yields something like:

```
> #<History id: 35, available: true, when: nil, msg: "my message", provider_id: 1, created_at: "2012-09-18 07:12:50", updated_at:
> "2012-09-18 07:12:50">
```

Same result using the scope on History such as:

```
provider.histories.active.recent.first & provider.histories.active.recent.first.inspect
```

What am I missing here? After doing Model.find.last why cant I then access the attributes of the model returned?

In the case like this where I really only want 1 attribute, what would be wrong with:

```
Model.find.last.some_attribute
```

Comment: Ack! I found the problem. There are some Providers that have no histories. So, yes sometimes there is a nil obj. Doh! For now I'm using this to handle the nil case: <%= provider.lastActive.msg unless provider.lastActive.nil?  %> other ideas welcome

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to remove the line:

```
attr_accessible :available, :msg
```

It's not right and will cause problems.

I don't understand why it would give a undefined method `msg' for nil:NilClass error, but take it out and see if that fixes it.

Also not that you should have an order method if you are getting the last.

Lastly, once you get it working, since you have the histories association, you can define lastActive as follows:

```
def last_active
  return histories.order(:id).last
end
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry no difference after removing the attr_accessible. My preference was to use the scopes declared in History to get the 1 most recent. I added the def last_active as an alternate sanity check but so far remain quite puzzled but this.